# Can an illusion hold weight?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, illusion

For this quesiton, I'm asking for RAW rulings.

Let's say you have a "standard" illusion over a pit, and the character believes it's real; does it support weight? (Typically the answer would be no, because it wasn't meant to, and belief means nothing — unlike the "Skittles" commercial of the people sitting on the Rainbow)

But what happens if the illusion is semi-real? How real can the shadowstuff that makes an illusion be made? I know it's real enough to damage others, but is it real enough to withstand weight?

What happens if someone is on this illusory area covering the pit when the illusion expires? Or it simply vanishes from existence and the unlucky sap drops below?

Or am I not seeing the whole picture here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to your question is - there is more than one kind of [illusion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#illusion).

**Glamers** and **figments** change your senses, so they can't hold up weight. Characters trying to stand on them will fall through (and immediately disbelieve, since they have proof the illusion was a fake).

> A figment spell creates a false sensation...
>
> A glamer spell changes a subject’s sensory qualities...
>
> Because figments and glamers are unreal, they cannot produce real effects the way that other types of illusions can.

**Shadows** can hold up weight just fine.

> A shadow spell creates something that is partially real from extradimensional energy. Such illusions can have real effects.

However, some shadow spells can be partially disbelieved, in which case there is a % chance that the object doesn't "work" and the creature falls through. See *[shadow conjuration](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shadowConjuration.htm)*:

> Shadow objects or substances have normal effects except against those who disbelieve them. Against disbelievers, they are 20% likely to work.

**Patterns** and **phantasms** affect the mind directly. These illusions can make someone *believe* they are standing on the floor, while in reality they have fallen down a pit.

> Like a figment, a pattern spell creates an image that others can see, but a pattern also affects the minds of those who see it or are caught in it.
>
> A phantasm spell creates a mental image that usually only the caster and the subject (or subjects) of the spell can perceive. This impression is totally in the minds of the subjects.

For any non-instantaneous spell, the effect disappears once the duration ends. Regardless of what kind of spell was creating the bridge (illusion, conjuration, evocation, what have you) the creature standing on it will fall in the hole.

Comment: So can a caster tell his teammates to deliberately fail their save against an effect to be able to cross a chasm they've made a semi-real bridge to cross?

Comment: @JesseCohoon While, for example, the spell *greater shadow conjuration* can simulate *major creation* to make a bridge, I'm pretty sure a Wiz13 has a better way than using her top-level spell to get her buddies across a chasm (cf. *dimension door*).

Comment: Bonus points for putting a sign halfway across the shadow bridge telling those who are crossing that the bridge isn't real...

Comment: No bonus points - you get a save against an illusion as soon as you interact with it, and standing on it is interacting with it.

Comment: For those curious as to the commercial cited in the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUmXhCmVaQg

Comment: Note that many glamours don't actually allow saving throws to disbelieve; You continue to perceive the illusion even if you know it's an illusion. *Invisibility* is the classic example: You can be perfectly aware there's an invisible creature in the room, and even grapple it, but you can't make a saving throw to see it.

Comment: @GMJoe but being grappled (if you counter by grappling back, or even trying to escape the grapple), would count as an attack with plain invisibility (thus ending the spell) vs True Invisibility

Comment: @JesseCohoon True, that; Grappling wasn't the best example. My point was that you can be completely aware of the existence of a glamour without any ability to see through it, which is a bit different to the save-to-disbelieve-on-interaction mechanic that many other illusions have.